# Two conditions in sending email to two different recipient in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating VBA code to send email when submit button is clicked. I have 2 conditions, example: in column `A` it will filter data that contains `"AD"` and will be sent to recipient A. and in column `G` if it contains `"13"` or `"14"` it will be filtered and sent to recipient B. I already got the 1st condition but I don't know how to add the second condition. else is not working.

```
Sub BSPProfitCenter_Rectangle3_Click()


    Const cFirst As Integer = 20
    Const cLast As Integer = 65
    Const cRequest As String = "New Request"

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = cFirst To cLast

        If Range("A" & i).Value = cRequest Then

            If Range("e" & i).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Provide the PC name from KE53"
                Exit Sub

            ElseIf Range("g" & i).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please provide the user responsible (Sector) maintained in KE53 for this PC"
                Exit Sub

            ElseIf Range("K" & i).Value = "" Then
                MsgBox "Provide the company code where the PC needs to be extended"
                Exit Sub

            End If
        End If
        Next i

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PROFITCENTER"
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$19:$L$65").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=AD*", Operator:=xlAnd


        ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Apps\" & "GSAP Asset Domain PC Request" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")


        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .to = "A"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "AD Request"
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Display

        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub


'here's the supposed to be additional validation'

        If Range("s" & i).Value <> "AD" Then
        If Range("G" & i).Value = "13" Or Range("G" & i).Value = "14" Then



        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="PROFITCENTER"
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$19:$L$65").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=13", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=14"


        ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Apps\" & "GSAP PC Request" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YYYY")



        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .to = "B"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "13 & 14 Request"
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Display

        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End If
        End If

End Sub
```

I wanted to have 2 conditions in one submit button but the second code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you say:

> in column A it will filter data that contains "AD"

while in code you write:

```
If Range("s" & i).Value <> "AD"
```

which indicated column `S`, not `A` - pay attention to that.

You got your `If`s wrong, because it look somewhat like this:

```
If Range("s" & i).Value <> "AD" Then
    If Range("G" & i).Value = "13" Or Range("G" & i).Value = "14" Then
        ' do all logic here
    End If
End If
```

Which also can be rewritten as:

```
If Range("s" & i).Value <> "AD" And (Range("G" & i).Value = "13" Or Range("G" & i).Value = "14") Then
    ' do all logic here
End If
```

You don't have any separation between those conditions, which you want to treat separately.

It should be written as:

```
If Range("s" & i).Value <> "AD" Then
    ' send mail to recipient A
End If
If Range("G" & i).Value = "13" Or Range("G" & i).Value = "14" Then
    ' send mail to recipient B
End If
```

Comment: First of all, you say:

in column A it will filter data that contains "AD"

while in code you write:

If Range("s" & i).Value <> "AD"
which indicated column S, not A - pay attention to that. - Apologies, i didnt made it clear. the column A was just my example.. i didnt meant it is the actual column.

Comment: since i have pre-validation that is in loop, i have ended it before sending the email. I am able to send the attachment if the "AD" criteria is met, but i can't add my next criteria which is <>"AD" & ="13" or = "14"